# 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa3 in position 28: invalid start byte

Tags: python, pandas, csv, unicode, utf-8

I am trying to read a CSV file from google drive with pandas library.
However, I've got a problem **"UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa3 in position 28: invalid start byte"**

My code

```
df = pd.read_csv("/content/gdrive/My Drive/data/OnlineRetail.csv")
```

Output

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_tokens()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_with_dtype()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._string_convert()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers._string_box_utf8()

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa3 in position 28: invalid start byte

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-65a06557fa8d> in <module>()
----> 1 df = pd.read_csv("/content/gdrive/My Drive/data/OnlineRetail.csv")

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in read_csv(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision)
    686     )
    687 
--> 688     return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    689 
    690 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    458 
    459     try:
--> 460         data = parser.read(nrows)
    461     finally:
    462         parser.close()

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in read(self, nrows)
   1196     def read(self, nrows=None):
   1197         nrows = _validate_integer("nrows", nrows)
-> 1198         ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
   1199 
   1200         # May alter columns / col_dict

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in read(self, nrows)
   2155     def read(self, nrows=None):
   2156         try:
-> 2157             data = self._reader.read(nrows)
   2158         except StopIteration:
   2159             if self._first_chunk:

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_column_data()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_tokens()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_with_dtype()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._string_convert()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers._string_box_utf8()

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa3 in position 28: invalid start byte
```

Comment: Try - `pd.read_csv('...',encoding='utf-8')`

Comment: after I try your suggestion
"UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa3 in position 79780: invalid start byte"

Comment: Or try `encoding=ascii`. Look [here](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/standard-encodings.html) for different types of encoding

Comment: "TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object." it's still not working.  :(

Comment: Alternatively you could try `read_csv(filename, encoding= 'unicode_escape')`

Comment: The obvious answer is it isn't encoded in UTF-8.  The byte `A3` represents the British pound sign (£) in both ISO-8859-1 (a.k.a. Latin-1) and cp1252 (a.k.a. Windows-1252) so it is likely one of those encodings if that is an expected character in the file at position 28.  Note that ISO-8859-1 can decode anything so you still have to look at the result to make sure there are no errors.  If you provided a hexdump of the first few lines of the CSV we could reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue. It may be not utf-8 encoding. Try to figure out what is it. You can do this by oening it in Notepad++.There are encoding menu on the top, look what is picked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

I've just had the same issue. CSV file written out by an online service. Opened in Atom notebook, encoding is UTF-8. But you count to the character which it identifies and it was "�" when it should have been "£". Find and replace all, and it is fixed.

Good luck.

Comment: If there is one non-UTF8 character there is likely to be more. If you replace all the question marks with the same thing then many will turn out to be wrong.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I met this situation(0xa3 issue) before, and I think this is an encoding issue. 
If your encoding is set with 'utf-8' or 'gbk', then you can try `encoding='ISO-8859-1'`. 
Good luck!